# Can't receive packets on android app

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp, android-broadcastreceiver

I can't receive any packets on my app. I have a computer running from console-php this script:

```
$broadcast_string='http://hellokitty/shownumber.html';
$port=2328;
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP); 
socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 1); 
while(true){
  socket_sendto($sock, $broadcast_string, strlen($broadcast_string), 0, '255.255.255.255', $port); 
  sleep(1);
  echo "Broadcasting ...\n";
}
```

on the other hand I got this code running on my phonegap app on the MainActivity.java file:

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.os.PowerManager; 
import android.os.PowerManager.WakeLock;
import android.content.Context;

import org.apache.cordova.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import android.util.Log;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;

public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{
    public static String URL = null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
          @Override
          public void run() {
          try {
            DatagramSocket socket;

            //Wakelock------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              WakeLock mWakeLock =  null,mPartialWakeLock = null;
              PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
              // lock used to keep the processor awake.
              mPartialWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, TAG);
              mPartialWakeLock.acquire();


              final WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
              WifiManager.MulticastLock lock = wifi.createMulticastLock("UDP");
              lock.acquire();
            //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            try {
              //Keep a socket open to listen to all the UDP trafic that is destined for this port
              //socket = new DatagramSocket(2328, InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0"));
              socket = new DatagramSocket(2328);
              socket.setBroadcast(true);
              URL = null;
              while (URL == null) {
                  System.out.println(getClass().getName() + ">>>Ready to receive broadcast packets!");

                  //Receive a packet
                  byte[] recvBuf = new byte[12000];
                  DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(recvBuf, recvBuf.length);
                  //socket.setSoTimeout(10000);
                  socket.receive(packet);

                  //Packet received
                  System.out.println(getClass().getName() + ">>>Discovery packet received from: " + packet.getAddress().getHostAddress());
                  System.out.println(getClass().getName() + ">>>Packet received; data: " + new String(packet.getData()));
                  String message = new String(packet.getData()).trim();

                  URL=message;
                  break;
              }
          } catch (IOException ex) {
                //Nothing
          }



          } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
            }
        });

          thread.start(); 

          while(URL == null){
            continue;
          }
          Log.d("net_discover",URL);
          super.loadUrl(URL);
      }
}
```

I've tested the network sniffing packets and traffic it's ok.
I've added the wakelock section since I've read that android blocks broadcast packets, but I'm still not getting anything on my device.

I'm working on a Motorola running Android 4.4.4

On the adb logcat, app is stuck on the msg "Ready to receive.." and that's all I get.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

I added code to my app to send packet before starting receiving and for my surprise it does receive it. So I started sending packets and sniffing the network from my computer and I don't see any. So doing some more research I found that the app is working on the lo interface (loopback, 127.0.0.1).

So my question now is, how do I make the app receive packets from wifi interface?